# Why does Heidegger say Biography is unimportant for Philosophy?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Why does Heidegger say that "regarding the personality of a philosopher, our only interest is that he was born at a certain time, that he worked, and that he died."?

Comment: Would you have a source where he says that?

Comment: beginning of his lectures on aristotle it seems @FrankHubeny

Comment: Please link the source so it can be included in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, Joseph Lutz

The quote comes, as you probably know, from Basic Concepts of Aristotelian Philosophy, p. 4 of the Metcalf & Tanzer translation, Indiana University Press, 2009.

## Philosophy contra biography

As always with Heidegger one is inclined to hesitate but in this case I think Heidegger's standpoint is straightforward. He is marginalising the life of Aristotle in order to concentrate on what principally interests H. as a philosopher, namely '*some basic concepts of Aristotelian philosophy*, specifically through an engagement with the *text* of the Aristotelian treatises' (Metcalf & Tanzer; italics in text: 3).

Basic concepts are characterised as 'not all, but *some*, and so presumably the *primary matters* with which Aristotelian research is occupied' (ibid.). These matters are to be identified from Metaphysics, Bk 5 or Delta (Δ) which is sometimes called Aristotle's 'philosophical lexicon' : principle (*arche*), cause, element, nature, necessity, oneness, being, substance, identity, prior and posterior, difference, part, potentiality and a number of others which you can readily check - and may already have done so.

The key point is that in examining these concepts, their interconnections and presuppositions, Heidegger is engaged in the purely philosophical task of penetrating and understanding their *specific conceptuality* (Metcalf & Tanzer: 4). What do they amount to as concepts? How are they grounded in other, previous concepts - those, for instance, of Plato, Socrates and the Presocratics ?

To these questions, no answers can be found and none should be sought in the life of Aristotle as a person. It makes no matter that he was born in Stagira, that he taught Alexander the Great, that he attended Plato's Academy or that in political ill-favour at the end of his life, with the fate of Socrates in mind, he left Athens lest it should 'sin against philosophy a second time'. Such personalia are the dust of philosophy, of no significance.

That at least is my understanding of Heidegger's anti- or non-biographical standpoint.

## Reading

M. Heidegger, Basic Concepts of Aristotelian Philosophy, tr.Metcalf & Tanzer, Indiana University Press, 2009.

Aristotle, The Metaphysics, tr. H. C Lawson-Tancred, London: Penguin Books, 1998.
ISBN 10: 0140446192 ISBN 13: 9780140446197,